# Protected & internal, not protected or internal

Tags: c#, internal, access-levels

Internal - public in assembly and private in other places.
 
Protected - only derived classes can have access to parent class members.
Protected internal - protected **OR** internal - public in assembly and protected in other places.
 
So, how to make parent class members accessible **ONLY** in assembly **AND** from derived classes?
If we are talking about IL, any ways to inject *famandassem* flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately such a restriction is not possible in C# today.  There is no keyword combination which will provide `protected` and `internal`.  This is supported at the CLR level, it is just not exposed in C#

Comment: It's worth mentioning that **C# 7.2** introduces [protected private](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected) modifier which provides such functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Also C++/CLI has 'ptrotected private' access modifier, member with it is accessible ONLY in derived classes ONLY in current assembly. You can find it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ke3a209d.aspx (the page is very long, just find 'private protected')